# explanation of friendly fire

Tags: etymology

I know the meaning of friendly fire, but I never thought about it too much, if you are shooting someone who is your brother in arms, it's not like I'm not going to shoot someone just referring mostly to FPS as you probably guessed already, how can the fire be 'friendly', any idea about the origin of the word?

Comment: Did you do any research you do prior to asking this question?

Comment: yes, there are too many results referring to albums, movies, and I'm still looking, and the explanations I found mostly explain what friendly fire is, which I'm already aware of

Comment: Hence the classic saying, "Friendly fire isn't."

Comment: Google isn't the best tool for researching phrases. Try encyclopedias and dictionaries specifically, e.g. Wikipedia: "Friendly fire is inadvertent firing towards one's own or otherwise friendly forces".

Comment: @MarkBeadles: "inadvertent"?

Comment: What is 'FPS'? And what does it have to do with the question?

Comment: @Mitch FPS is frames per second. High-end cameras can fire off some really high FPS. Some them are a real fusillade. If you use spray-and-pray at an action shot, you might catch the right moment not out of skill but out of the luck of friendly fire. The Nikon V1/J1 cameras have the highest FPS in regular consumer models, at 1200 FPS. Played back at a normal 24 or 30 fps, it’s like having ¹⁄₄₀ slow-motion photography.

Comment: The [OED’s definition of “friendly fire”](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/74658#eid3725563) is *“Mil.* Of troops, equipment, etc.: of, belonging to, or in alliance with one's own forces; spec. resulting in accidental damage by allied troops to one's own installations, aircraft, or personnel, esp. as in ***friendly fire.”*** Seems like General Reference to me.

Comment: Plain and simple: *friendly fire* is the opposite of *hostile fire*.

Comment: @Mitch: FPS is probably First Person Shooter (video game) in this context.

Comment: @MarkBeadles I checked wikipedia and that is the definition of the expression, like I said in my first comment

Comment: "Friendly" does not simply mean "pleasant and nice". It also has the meaning "Person or entity on the same side of a conflict."

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you consider "enemy" to be the opposite of "friend," the any fire you come under in battle is either from your enemies or your friends. That from your friends is "friendly" in the locative sense (coming from your friends) rather than describing the behavior of friends.